# Making More Than One Circle in Java

Tags: java, javafx

I have a project in class where I need to display a traffic light with simply three cirlces. I started with the yellow one, and then attempted to add a red one in some random other place just to see if I could do it, however the yellow one is the only one showing. I can't tell if the red one is somehow underneath the yellow one, but in any case it doesn't make much sense to me as to why the red circle isn't showing.

```
package tryingGraphicsStuff;
import javafx.application.Application; 
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.text.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

public class TryingGraphicsStuff extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // create circle
                Circle circle = new Circle(); 
                circle.setCenterX(150);
                circle.setCenterY(150);
                circle.setRadius(50);
                circle.setFill(Color.RED);
                // place on pane
                StackPane p = new StackPane();
                p.getChildren().add(circle);
                // ensure it stays centered if window resized
                //circle.centerXProperty().bind(p.widthProperty().divide(2)); 
                //circle.centerYProperty().bind(p.heightProperty().divide(2));

                Circle circleTwo = new Circle();
                circleTwo.setCenterX(400);
                circleTwo.setCenterY(400);
                circleTwo.setRadius(50);
                circleTwo.setFill(Color.YELLOW);
                // place on pane
                p.getChildren().add(circleTwo);


                // create scene from pane
                Scene scene = new Scene(p, 300, 1000);

                // place scene on stage
                stage.setTitle("Circle");
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.show();
    }
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`StackPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html) "lays out its children in a back-to-front stack". (The stack here is in z-coordinates). It is a "layout pane" which actually manages the placement of the child nodes for you. Consequently, the `centerX` and `centerY` properties of the circles are ignored, and they appear one on top of the other in the order they are added (so the red one is underneath the yellow one, and the only one you see is the yellow one). By default, the stack pane centers them.

All "layout panes" position the nodes for you. For example, a `VBox` will position nodes in a vertical stack, with the first one at the top, the second below, and so on. So if you used a `VBox` instead of a `StackPane`, the circles would appear one below the other (in the y-direction), but note they would still not respect the `centerX` and `centerY` properties.

The `Pane` class itself does not manage the layout of its child nodes; so if you want to use the coordinates for shape objects, `Pane` is probably your best option. `Group` behaves similarly, but takes on the bounds of the union of its child bounds, so it acts like `Pane` but its local coordinate system is different.

The following demo shows all these options. Again, `Pane` will be the one that behaves in an intuitive way.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CircleLayoutExample extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TabPane tabs = new TabPane();

        tabs.getTabs().add(createTab(new StackPane()));
        tabs.getTabs().add(createTab(new VBox()));
        tabs.getTabs().add(createTab(new Pane()));
        tabs.getTabs().add(createTab(new Group()));

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabs, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Tab createTab(Pane pane) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(150, 150, 50, Color.RED);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(400, 400, 50, Color.YELLOW);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2);

        Tab tab = new Tab(pane.getClass().getSimpleName());
        tab.setContent(pane);
        return tab ;
    }

    // annoyingly, Pane and Group do not have a common superclass with a getChildren()
    // method, so just reproduce the code...
    private Tab createTab(Group pane) {
        Circle c1 = new Circle(150, 150, 50, Color.RED);
        Circle c2 = new Circle(400, 400, 50, Color.YELLOW);

        pane.getChildren().addAll(c1, c2);

        Tab tab = new Tab(pane.getClass().getSimpleName());
        tab.setContent(pane);
        return tab ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yeah your both the circles are overlapping.
You can simply use a `VBox` instead of `StackPane`. It will solve your issue.

```
VBox p = new VBox();
```

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have suggested, using a [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html) would help you out the most here, since it will automatically put its children into a vertical row.  Here is a brief snippet using an array (so you can make as many circles as you want)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;

public class TryingGraphicsStuff extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

            Circle[] circle = new Circle[3];          // create 3 circles
            VBox vBox = new VBox();                   // vbox will put circles in vertical row
            vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);            // center circles

            for(int i = 0; i < circle.length; i++){
                circle[i] = new Circle(50);           // initialize circles with radius of 50
                vBox.getChildren().add(circle[i]);
            }

            circle[0].setFill(Color.RED);
            circle[1].setFill(Color.YELLOW);
            circle[2].setFill(Color.GREEN);

            // add vbox to scene

            Scene scene = new Scene(vBox, 300, 800);
            stage.setTitle("Circle");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Application.launch(args);
    }

}
```

As always, *please* understand the code and don't just mindlessly copy and paste. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

I'm actually a bit confused by the code above. According to your numbers the red one should be the one showing and not the yellow one. Your scene is only 300px wide and you center the yellow circle at 400 which will put it out of view (having a radius of only 50).

Either increase your scene size or move your circle inside your view.

Comment: No, both `Circle`s are on screen, but the yellow one is painted over the red one. You can easily verify this by using `Color.YELLOW.deriveColor(0, 1, 1, 0.5)` (yellow with alpha=0.5) instead of `Color.YELLOW` which results in an orange circle being displayed.